# Windows Mobile 6.5.3 and Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, mobile, sleep

I'm building and application for a motorola handheld using Windows Mobile 6.5.3 and I need to have a thread running on the background doing some checks every X seconds.

Currently it looks something like this:

```
public static void Start()
{
     while(validate())
     {
         // do something
         Thread.sleep(interval);
     }
}
```

The problem I have is that this is resource heavy because the thread is still using memory.

Is there a better way to do this?

The answer may or may not make use of multiple threads, I just want to do a certain task every X seconds.

Comment: Whatever you do, it will use some memory.  Managed threads commit 1MB of stack but how much of that is actually paged in for a simple Sleep() loop is very small.  The code and data associated with 'do something' will presumably add to that.  How much RAM memory is your Sleep() thread using?  Presumably, you don't care about the page-file commit if you have only the one sleepy thread.

Comment: @MartinJames - does Windows Mobile even have a page-file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer to run some code on a set interval without blocking a thread when you have nothing else to be doing.

Comment: Would you mind to expand your thoughts about "without blocking a thread"?

Comment: @Hrodger What is there to expand on?  You create a timer, that takes virtually no time, at which point the thread can go on doing whatever and the timer will be responsible for executing the code you've told it to run at the set intervals.  It does exactly what you need.